# Android/SQLite: Way to set default sort order back to ROWID

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sorting, android-sqlite

I am having problems in my app because SQLite somehow has changed the behavior of the default sort order.

Until SQLite 3.7.5 (at least) when a query does not have an "ORDER BY" clause, the results were sorted by rowid. Now with SQLite 3.8.6 they come ordered by the primary key.

**SQLite 3.7.5:**

```
select rowid, id, name from users;

rowid   id    name
--------------------
1       10    John
2       15    Peter
3       11    Mary
4       14    Sam
```

**SQLite 3.8.6:**

```
select rowid, id, name from users;

rowid   id    name
-------------------
1       10    John
3       11    Mary
4       14    Sam
2       15    Peter
```

I have uncountable queries to change, where I have just to add "ORDER BY ROWID".

**Does SQLite have a parameter where I could set the default sort order back to ROWID?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_reverse_unordered_selects) says:

> SQLite makes no guarantees about the order of results if a SELECT omits the ORDER BY clause. Even so, the order of results does not change from one run to the next, and so many applications mistakenly come to depend on the arbitrary output order whatever that order happens to be. However, sometimes new versions of SQLite will contain optimizer enhancements that will cause the output order of queries without ORDER BY clauses to shift. When that happens, applications that depend on a certain output order might malfunction.

Comment: OK, got it! Sounds like I'll have to change all queries.